# syntax error near unexpected token while executing a python file

Tags: linux, python-2.7, terminal, fedora

I was trying to execute a python file which is not saved in the python directory but in a different one in linux (fedora) terminal. What I tried was:

```
$ exec(vsh1.py)
```

which resulted an error:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token 'vsh1.py'
```

Could anybody find a solution please...
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Locate your python's source file

```
find / -name vsh1.py
```

and once located run

```
 python /path_you_found/vsh1.py
```

if you want your script to be seen from any location for the interpreter you have to add it to PYTHONPATH:

```
 PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path_you_found/vsh1.py
```

if your script in the same directory you can just run

```
python ./vsh1.py
```

Comment: It works perfect...I am new to linux so thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

`exec(python2.7 filename.py)` This will be the command.

Answer (score 0):

You want this:

```
python vsh1.py
```

Or if you have your script set up properly with executable permissions and a "shebang line":

```
./vsh1.py
```